# Is this narration , Musannaf Ibn Abi Shayba 23945, authentic?

Tags: hadith, uloom-al-hadith

I have tried googling about it but cannot find anything satisfying.

> Narrated ‘Urwah: ‘Aisha used to order to make a habit of or taking in regular intervals seven ‘ajwah dates, in the state of fasting for seven mornings. (Musannaf Ibn Abi Shayba, Hadith 23945)

Could you please help?

If there's any problem in my question please inform me.

Comment: You will need to provide a quote of the hadith.

Comment: @III-AK-III I edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest hadith that I could find in Musannaf Ibn Abi Shaiba is hadith 23479, not hadith 23945:

> حدثنا أبو بكر قال: حدثنا ابن نمير، قال: أخبرنا هشام بن عروة، عن أبيه، عن عائشة: أَنَّهَا كَانَتْ تَأْمُرُ مِنَ الدُّوَّامِ أَوِ الدُّوَّارِ بِسَبْعِ تَمَرَاتِ عَجْوَةٍ فِي سَبْعِ غَدَوَاتٍ عَلَى الرِّيقِ
>
> <sub>**NOTE.** My own translation, so treat with care.</sub>
>
> Narrated by Abu Bakr who said: I was told by Ibn Numair who said: Hishām ibn 'Urwa informed me that his father informed him through 'Ā'isha: "She ['Ā'isha] used to order for vertigo or dizziness seven *'ajwah* dates for seven days to have them first thing [on an empty stomach]."
>
> <sub>— [Musannaf Ibn Abi Shaiba, Vol. 5, pp. 37, Hadith 23479](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33038/26506#p1)</sub>

As per *Anīs as-Sāri Takhrīj Ahādīth al-Bukhāri* [Vol. 11, pp. 1229](https://al-maktaba.org/book/32900/8018#p11), the hadith as attributed to 'Ā'isha ([mawqūf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith_terminology#Mawquf)) is authentic.

For your information, hadith 23945 is about a different topic and I doubt this is the one you are looking for:

> حدثنا أبو بكر قال: حدثنا يزيد بن هارون، عن حماد بن سلمة، عن علي بن زيد، عن ربيعة بن النابغة، عن أبيه، عن علي، عن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم قال كُنْتُ نَهَيْتُكُمْ عَنْ هَذِهِ الْأَوْعِيَةِ فَاشْرَبُوا فِيهَا، وَاجْتَنِبُوا كُلَّ مَا أَسْكَرَ
>
> <sub>**NOTE.** My own translation, so treat with care.</sub>
>
> Narrated by Abu Bakr who said: I was told by Yazīd ibn Harūn through Hammād ibn Salama through 'Ali ibn Zaid through Rabī'a ibn an-Nābigha through his father through 'Ali that the Prophet ﷺ said: "I had previously forbidden you from [using] these bowls; now you can drink in them but shun everything that intoxicates."
>
> <sub>— [Musannaf Ibn Abi Shaiba, Vol. 5, pp. 86, Hadith 23945](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33038/27035#p1)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

This Athar occurs in the Musannaf of Ibn Abi Shaybah with this numbering (23945) in the edition of Awamah. In Luhaydan's edition, it is (23826). It occurs as (23479) with Dar Kutub Al-Ilmiyah and in another edition, it occurs as (22991). It does not occur in the edition of Usamah at all (according to the index, see: 14/453) but it does occur in the edition of Shithri (25023) and he called it Sahih. Of the 6 editions I checked, only Shithri commented on its authenticity. It's Isnad was also authenticated in the Takhrij of Fath Al-Bari (as mentioned above).

As for its Isnad, it is Abu Bakr (Ibn Abi Shaybah) from (Abu Bakr) Ibn Numayr (Al-Hamdani) from Hisham bin Urwah (Al-Asadi) from his father (Urwah bin Az-Zubayr) from A'ishah (bint Abi Bakr) and all of them are Thiqah.